# Combinations on multisets and ordered pairs

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multisets

I came across this question while doing some revisions. There are 3 parts to this question. One of them I asked here before.

Suppose you have a series of scrabble tiles, each tile has one letter on it, and a point value in the bottom right-hand corner (e.g. "C" is worth 3 points).

[image]

Note that there are some repeated tiles. For example, the two S tiles are identical. For the first 3 parts of the question, we place all of the above tiles into a bag and then draw 2 tiles out of the bag.

1. How many **sets** of two tiles can be selected from the bag if we insist that the two chosen tiles contain **different** letters?
2. How many different **multisets** of 2 tiles can be selected from the bag?
3. Suppose that I take one tile from the bag, and then take another tile. How many possible ordered pairs of tiles can I form in this way?

---

***My method***

1. I cancelled out the repeating tiles, so I have "C O M P S I T N",

   then, from these 8 tiles I did $_8C_2$ = 28
2. I'm not sure how to do combinations with multisets
3. I'm also confused about "ordered pairs"

Can anyone help me out in solving these questions? Also in checking if I did question 1 correctly, because I have my doubts. Thanks in advance

Comment: For (2) you can take your answer to (1) and add the number of possible pairs of identical letters. For (3) you will count $(C,O)$ and $(O,C)$ as distinct ordered pairs

Comment: @Henry so for the multiset part I'll have to do $28 + 3=31$, since possible pairs of identical letters are $_3C_2 \times _2C_2 \times _2C_2$?

Comment: Yes - you could just say $OO,SS,II$ are the three possible pairs.

Comment: @Henry, ah okk, thank you so much. Can you elaborate more on the ordered pairs part?

Comment: It is similar: count distinct pairs  by finding how many choices for the first tile and then how many for the second tile; then count identical pairs as you just did; then add.  You should get slightly less than double the answer to (2).

Comment: @Henry, ohh alright. I understand, thank you so much

Comment: I think if the question is just about number of ways of choosing two tiles with given restrictions, then ${8 \choose 2}$ works for $(1)$. Adding pairs where tiles can repeat gives $(2)$. I somehow interpreted the question very differently yesterday and I ended up solving a a lot more complicated problem :)